# Spring Boot and PostgreSQL - No data printed

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Spring Boot application that's connected to Heroku so I'd like to try to integrate postgreSQL into my app.

I created the database and a very basic table:
[table creation and data insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VVyq.png)

In my SpringBoot app I created a **repository**, an **entity** and then I'm just trying to print out the first name.

Here's the **JPA repo**:

```
@Repository
public interface MytableRepository extends JpaRepository<Mytable, Integer>{
}
```

Here's the **entity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
public class Mytable {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
}
```

And finally here's my controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestingStationController {

@Autowired
MytableRepository MytableRepo;

@RequestMapping(value={"test", "Test", "TEST", "TestingStation", "testingstation", "Testingstation", "testingStation"})
public ModelAndView testingStationController(ModelAndView mv) {
    mv.setViewName("TestingStation/TestingStation");
    System.out.println(MytableRepo.findAll());
    List<Mytable> mytable = MytableRepo.findAll();
    for (Mytable mytable2 : mytable) {
        System.out.println("name=" + mytable2.getFirstName());
    }
    return mv;
}

}
```

In the end all I'm trying to do is just print something out of this table. The app builds just fine and I don't seem to have any connection issues. Just in case here's a sample of my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-224-120-186.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/ddd3l9bfia0463

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Leaving out username and password for obvious reasons. No console errors, no crashes, no connection issues. Just prints empty brackets when I do the first print and then doesn't print anything in the foreach loop. Any help would be much, much appreciated.

Comment: And that data is removed again. YOu let hibernate create the schema which will wipe it at startup. Set `generate-ddl` to `false` and/or `ddl-auto` to `none` to preserve what you have.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer Mr. Deinum. That did not fix it however did bring up a new error stating `o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : table "mytable" does not exist, skipping`

Comment: Which means that you are looking at a different database than hibernate does (and it apparently needs to create the tables for it). Or did you actually commit that data and changes to the database? If not it won't be visible .

Comment: ya I just went and restarted my postgres client's connection to my DB to make sure. Then ran a quick select on my table and I see the data

Comment: Then the only conclusion can be that you are looking at different databases. Check the connection URL for both yourself as well as the application.

Comment: ya it's guaranteed I have the right URL, it's the same I'm using in my postgres client. The only thing I keep thinking it might be is the schema but I have it defined in the app properties and I'm not getting any errors with that definition

Comment: But doesn't heroky override the JDBC url to connect to its own Postgres instance? The only logical conclusion is that you are looking/using different databases for some reason or the other else the data would exist, so if you really committed the data and see it on your local DB tooling and the app doesn't see, it means they are using different database or schemas.

Comment: ah good point, so even though I'm getting a successful connection I'm not actually hitting the DB, just their root. Ty sir, that at least gives me a starting point to dig into. Have a great one !

Answer (score 0):

It turns out if you define a column name with a capital letter, Hibernate will change it with an underscore. So my table not found was some weird error but when I changed the column names to all lower case I can finally print :)